# mdThemingProvider Angular Material Error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I can't figure out why $mdThemingProvider crashes.

```
var app = angular.module( 'aBMain',['ngMaterial']);
  console.log('3');

app.config(function($mdThemingProvider){
  console.log('4');

  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('pink')
    .accentPalette('orange');
```

});

Codepen : http://codepen.io/turcuciprian/pen/mPwBOm check out the console. It's supposed to output 4, why does it hang here? (with an error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two references:

1. angular-animate.js (or angular-animate.min.js) [CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-animate.js)
2. angular-aria.js (or angular-aria.min.js) [CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-aria.js)

Always debug with the non-minified versions. As soon as I changed your Codepen to use the non-minified versions the exact reason for the error was spelled out in the console.